# Twitter: OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104

Tags: php, twitter

> Twitter: OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104

> Twitter: Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 bytes
> received

This are the two errors I'm getting (randomly) while trying to upload a video file in chunks into Twitter.

```
1.5MB file = Most of the times uploads, sometimes gives error
10MB file = Always gives error (one of the above, randomly)
20MB file = Always gives error (one of the above, randomly)
```

My code is pretty much exactly like this one: [Upload Twitter video error (PHP). API response: Segments do not add up to provided total file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429149/upload-twitter-video-error-php-api-response-segments-do-not-add-up-to-provid) and I'm using the [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) library.

```
function append($mediaId, $fileUrl)
{
    $segmentIndex = 0;

    $handle = fopen($fileUrl, 'r');

    while (!feof($handle)) 
    {
        $chunk = fread($handle, 4 * 1024 * 1024); // 4mb 

        $params = ['command' => 'APPEND', 'media_id' => $mediaId, 'media_data' => base64_encode($chunk), 'segment_index' => $segmentIndex];
        $this->tw->uploadCustom('media/upload', $params);

        $segmentIndex++;
    }
}
```

I know by debugging that the errors are thrown in this function.

The [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-append) says:

> "media" The raw binary file content being uploaded. It must be
> <= 5 MB, and cannot be used with media_data.
>
> "media_data" The base64-encoded chunk of media file. It must be
> <= 5 MB and cannot be used with media. Use raw binary (media
> parameter) when possible.

I tried both options and no success. What am I missing? Why can't I upload bigger files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**.

All I had to do is change the library I was using to https://github.com/jublo/codebird-php and it started working immediatelly without any major change.